# Haskell Syntax Error at seemingly random locations

Tags: haskell, syntax

This code was working a few minutes ago and after I restarted my ghci, it stopped working..
Now I'm getting random errors on either `where`, `snst` or `size`. (not sure what I've changed to cause each separate error)

Can someone point out what's wrong with my syntax?

```
instance Array Tree where
    new n x  
        | n <= 0    = Leaf
        | odd n     = Node n nst x nst
        | even n    = Node n (Node (n `div` 2) snst x snst) x snst
        where nst = (new (n `div` 2) x)
              snst = (new (n `div` 2 - 1) x)

    size Leaf            = 0
    size (Node s _ _ _)  = s
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As always in these cases, make sure that there are no tabs hiding.

I checked that your way to indent `where` is valid. So unless there is an error before the `instance` declaration I can't see any syntactical errors.

Also, one idea to eliminate sources of errors would be to move out the definition of `new`.

```
myNew :: ...
myNew n x  
        | n <= 0    = Leaf
        | odd n     = Node n nst x nst
        | even n    = Node n (Node (n `div` 2) snst x snst) x snst
        where nst = (new (n `div` 2) x)
              snst = (new (n `div` 2 - 1) x)

instance Array Tree where
    new = myNew

    size Leaf            = 0
    size (Node s _ _ _)  = s
```

Try this and see if that compiles

Comment: That work's just fine. Thanks. But is there any explanation as to why the way I did it caused compilation to fail?

Comment: @user1043625 Well. The syntax for function definitions within instances is limited. As far as I remembered, you were only allowed to have one equation per function. But obviously you have 2 for `size` here. So I'm confused by this as well.

Comment: @Tarrasch: that's incorrect. There is no such limitation for function definitions within instance declarations.